# How to set cursor position at the end in Extjs HtmlEditor

Tags: html-editor

Is there a way to set cursor position at the end in Extjs HtmlEditor? I did not find any solution for this and I dont want to insert text but only need default cursor at the end of text on focus.
any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: did any one have any comment or solution to above?

Comment: Just set the text alignment to the right

Comment: How to set text alignment to right in html editor ??

Comment: cursor is not visible at all in chrome browser only and the position issue is on all the other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't have a direct way to do this, but you can do it like this:

```
 editor.getDoc().body.innerHTML = '<div style="text-align:right;">&#8203</div>';
 editor.updateLayout();
 editor.focus();
```

Comment: can not align to right. is there other solution for the same. and the other issue is we are not getting cursor in chrome browser on focus. can you please give the fix for chrome focus as well